# Field not being sorted in ascending order in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL:

```
;WITH times AS (
    SELECT '0830' AS t
    UNION
    SELECT '0930' AS t
    UNION
    SELECT '1030' AS t
    UNION
    SELECT '1130' AS t
    UNION
    SELECT '1230' AS t
)
SELECT t as time
FROM times
;
```

When I execute this in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), it displayed correctly as

```
0830
0930
1030
1130
1230
```

However, when I put this into a drop down list inside Visual Studio 2010, the list becomes incorrectly sorted:

```
1030
1130
1230
830
930
```

The `0` is disappearing from the `0830` and `0930` and both `0830` to `0930` is being shifted from the 1st two items in the list to the last two items.

How can I make the drop-down show the list in the correct order?

Comment: Your application is sorting it based on the character values (i.e. a string sort, as opposed to a numeric one).  If SQL Server is handing the application the data correctly, then this sounds like an application issue.

Comment: How about ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, time)? Or using a TIME data type instead of a string?

Comment: Despite the lack of an `ORDER BY`, this is an application issue, probably something to do with data types and how the list is getting populated.

Comment: While the solution seems to have been simple enough, I wonder if the difference could be a plan issue based on different session settings (e.g. the same kind of issue that often causes an app to be slow but SSMS to be fast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specials thanks to Shark, Aaron Bertrand and Jon Seigel that have enlighten me.

I have use the `ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, time)` and it now solved the application issue problem. (Fortunately, the change to the SQL statement was a quick way to solve this problem)